# does numpy runs faster than OpenCL?

Tags: python, numpy, pyopencl

I tried some basic examples in pyopencl and noticed, that whatever I do, numpy runs faster than pyopengl. I run my scripts on a Intel i5 embedded HD4400. Clearly nothing special, but numpy runs minimum twice as fast as pyopengl. Last script I try:

```
import pyopencl as cl
from pyopencl import algorithm
import numpy as np
from time import time
from pyopencl.clrandom import rand
from pyopencl.array import to_device

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
    q = np.random.random_integers(-10**6,high=10**6, size=2**24)
    r = to_device(queue, q)
    begin = time()
    out, count, even = algorithm.copy_if(r, "ary[i] < 42", queue=queue)
    out.get()
    print("OpenCL takes {:9.6F} seconds".format(time() - begin))
    begin = time()
    b = q[q<42]
    print("numpy takes {:9.6F} seconds".format(time() - begin))
```

output:

```
OpenCL takes  1.223419 seconds
numpy takes  0.269451 seconds
```

Why didn't I see some advantages in parallelism? Also I appreciate links to well structued (py)?opencl tutorials or docs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Comparing the two on a single, extremely cheap operation is not a very good comparison.

For most devices, OpenCL will have to move all the data to and from the device (e.g. from main memory to GPU memory, then back), costing more than the operation itself when the operation is trivial. It also has to compile/transfer the code to perform the operation, which has non-zero cost, synchronize between device and host, etc. Try finding real work to do (ideally, real work without conditional branching); the more real work done without data transfer to and from the device, the better OpenCL will do. Mind you, `numpy` will still do well, because it will use vectorized operations itself when available; SSE operations may not scale the way GPGPU code does, but when the operations are simple and you don't need to do memory transfers to and from the device, `numpy` can do quite well.

For comparison, you might try checking just how long the data transfer itself is taking; assuming `pyopencl` doesn't optimize it out, you might just try a noop operation that just send the data to the device, then pulls it back, and see what sort of overhead the data transfer is incurring. From there, you can see what sort of basic overhead `pyopencl` involves; if `numpy` isn't doing enough work to significantly outweigh that overhead, then `pyopencl` won't help.

Comment: Exactly! I would add a simple real life analogy: Its like trying a car for 5 meters, and concluding that walking was faster. We had to take into account starting the car, picking up pace, etc. Time invested for all those steps would pay off if the distance to cover is large. It is all about tradeoffs associated each tool. (walking is numpy and OpenCL is the Car)

Comment: A better analogy: Calculating doubles of 100 single digit numbers. Typing in the number in a calculator, and copying the digits back on to the paper would be slower than mental calculation. But for multiplying one hundred 5 digit numbers with 5 digit numbers, a calculator is better (unless you are in the league of Shakuntala Devi).

Here, mental calculation is numpy and the calculator is OpenCL

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed running on the embedded chip, transfer shouldn't be too large an overhead. But also note that this trivial operation is memory-bound; and both numpy and opencl code are fetching from the same memory system; so you shouldn't really expect to be gaining anything in this benchmark. But using opencl does force you to make two additional passes over the memory, to copy in and out of the (in-ram) opencl context. Still, the opencl apparently has additional overhead that I cannot really account for; maybe nobody ever bothered making halfway decent opencl drivers for this chipset?